# issue in setting php page parameters and adding value in parameters using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xampp

i am not getting value of qnty in query can anyone tell me what mistake i am doing. actually i am beginner so please correct this code and help me how i can add value of quantity box in php page parameter where i am getting other values using anchor tag.

```
<a id="btn1" href="sale.php?tag=<?php echo $_REQUEST['tag'];?>
```

&btn=&&pro_id=pro_id?> &name=pro_name;?>&price=price?>&">

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['pro_id'])) {
    $txt = $_REQUEST['pro_id'];
    $txt1 = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $txt2 = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $txt4 = $_REQUEST['bill'];
    $txt3 = $_REQUEST['qnty'];
    $d = date("d \- F \- Y ");
    $cart = session_id();
    $query = "INSERT INTO cart (cart_id, pro_id, pro_name, quantity, price, bill,date) 
                     values ('$cart', '$txt','$txt2','$txt3', '$txt1','$txt1'*2, '$d' )";
    mysql_db_query("medical_wholesale_store", $query);
    header("location:sale.php");
}
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var qnty = $("#qty").val();
            a = $("#btn1").attr("href") + "qnty=" + qnty;
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here is pic of adding php parameters and jquery function along with html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InPmt.png)

Comment: you question is not clear. Could you explain it a bit more ! Also dont put image, put code so that it will be easy for users to test and give solution !

Comment: In the sql you have `'$txt1'*2` ? that looks wrong

Comment: ok let me explain you my question. i am making cart system i am adding values in cart using php parameters but couldnot get value from textbox i.e, quantity from textbox. i am trying to do it using jquery above is my jquery code. but every thing is being added instead of quantity in quantity column i am getting 0 instead of value. can u help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: that's working right RamRaider but not getting qnty in quantity column

Comment: Without the form it's hard to tell what is going on but from the javascript function it looks like you are trying to set the `href` attribute on a button - is that correct? Button's don't have an href attribute ( at least not in valid html ) and I still believe that bit in the sql is wrong

Comment: should i post whole page of my code??

Comment: here is anchor tag which i am using to get parameters: `<a  id="btn1" href="sale.php?tag=<?php echo $_REQUEST['tag'];?>&btn=&&pro_id=<?php echo $object->pro_id?>
                  &name=<?php echo $object->pro_name;?>&price=<?php echo $object->price?>&"></a>`

Comment: And if you hover the mouse over this link does it look like you expect? there is some funny markup there ( ie: double `&` ), trailing `&` and `&btn=&&pro_id=<?php etc`

Comment: that btn&& is submit button name and parameter. i have used a textbox which is autocomplete from database and then press submit to fetch the result from database then add this result into cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues as far as I can see with your code.

1. In the recordset iteration loop you are including the same stylesheet.
2. You are repeating the input element with id `qty` ~ this is not valid
3. The `a` link has the id `btn1` - this is also being repeated
4. The javscript function is also being repeated
5. The sum of column widths equals 99% rather than 100%

Because each is being repeated it will be impossible to know which element is being targeted properly. Hopefully what follows might help you solve your problems - no jQuery, just regular javascript ( I never use it )

That all said and done - your code is, I'm afraid to say, vulnerable to SQL injection and you should really think about migrating your code to use `mysqli` or `PDO` as they both support prepared statements which help mitigate against this danger! Good luck.

```
<?php

if ( isset($_REQUEST['pro_id'] ) ) {
    $txt = $_REQUEST['pro_id'];
    $txt1 = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $txt2 = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $txt4 = $_REQUEST['bill'];
    $txt3 = $_REQUEST['qnty'];
    $d = date("d \- F \- Y ");
    $cart = session_id();
    $query = "INSERT INTO cart ( `cart_id`, `pro_id`, `pro_name`, `quantit`y, `price`, `bill`, `date` ) 
                     values ( '$cart', '$txt','$txt2','$txt3', '$txt1','".( $txt1 * 2 )."', '$d' )";
    /* Debug sql to ensure it looks OK - test in gui? */
    echo $query;

    mysql_db_query("medical_wholesale_store", $query);
    header("location:sale.php");
}

/* execute sql query */

echo '
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>stock</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>expiry</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>';

/* semi-pseudo code snippet */
while( $object = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ){

    $unique=uniqid();/* do not really need this */
    echo "
        <tr><!-- add content -->
            <td>{$object->pro_id}</td>
            <td>{$object->pro_name}</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td>etc</td>
            <td><input type='number' name='qty' value=1 style='width:80px'/></td>
            <td>
                <a class='salebttn' id='{$unique}' href='sale.php?tag={$_REQUEST['tag']}&btn={$unique}&pro_id={$object->pro_id}&name={$object->pro_name}&price={$object->price}&bill=UNKNOWN_ENTITY'></a>
            </td>
        </tr>"; 
}

echo '
    </table>';

?>

<script>
    /* Find all links that are used within your table that have a particular class */
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('a.salebttn');
    for( var n in col ) if( col[n].nodeType==1 ){
        col[n].onclick=function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            var el=typeof( event.target )!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;
            var href=el.getAttribute('href');

            /* need to find the value of the input qty so we traverse the dom to find it */
            var qty=el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"][name="qty"]')[0].value;
            document.location.replace( href + '&qty='+qty );
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your precious work and time. i am grateful to you. this will help me alot